# Sum of Top 5 Products by Sales in Inventory in Power BI (DAX)

Tags: memory, powerbi, dax

I have a sales table with transaction details on the products purchased. I also have a table with warehouse inventory information for each product. I'm trying to get the volume of the top 5 products by warehouse.

I believe the DAX below should work, but I'm running into a memory error. Is there another way to achieve this?

```
TopFive =
VAR top5 =
    TOPN ( 5, SUMMARIZE ( 'Sales', 'Sales'[Product] ), [Sales Count] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Inventory'[Count of Products] ),
        FILTER (
            'Inventory',
            CONTAINS ( top5, 'Sales'[Product], 'Inventory'[Product] )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a Boolean filter rather than a table filter will be more efficient?

Try this and see if it helps:

```
TopFive =
VAR Top5 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        TOPN (
            5,
            SUMMARIZE ( 'Sales', 'Sales'[Product], "Count", [Sales Count] ),
            [Count]
        ),
        "Product", 'Sales'[Product]
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Inventory'[Count of Products] ),
        'Inventory'[Product] IN Top5
    )
```

Maybe also try `TREATAS(Top5, 'Inventory'[Product])` instead of `'Inventory'[Product] IN Top5` in the above.

Comment: Thank you for your response on this! I'm still having performance issues using the code provided. Should there be a many to many relationship between 'Inventory'[Product] and 'Sales'[Product]?

Comment: After removing the relationship, the measure works perfect! Thank you!